# How to use in a Server Handler an object (flextable) created in another function

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I'm trying to build an app like the following:
in the doGet function I build the app

```
function doGet() {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');
  var Table = _table_create(some arguments);
  ...
  panel.add(Table);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

The table is created by a function since I need to create several similar tables with some variable arguments during runtime and I can't predict when and how many. Thus I have a function _table_create that creates the table containing a button

```
function _table_create(arguments) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var Table = app.createFlexTable();
  ...
  var handler1 = app.createServerHandler("handler");
  handler1.addCallbackElement(Table);
  Table.setWidget(x,y,app.createButton("button", handler1).setId("button_"+Table.getId()));
  ...
  return Table
}
```

and I want to write an Handler linked to the button in the table that adds some widgets in the table.

```
function handler(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var table_id = (e.parameter.source).split('_');
  table_id = table_id[0];
  var table = app.getElementById(table_id);
  Logger.log(table.getType()); //// prints GENERIC
  ...
  table.setWidget(x,y,app.createTextBox());
  return app;
}
```

but when I click the button I get an error message that says it doesn't find a method `setWidget(string,number,TextBox)` for table.
I think the problem is in the fact I defined the callback element `Table` in a function that << dies >> after creating the table and this callback element get lost for the handler. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok, the error message is (for once) very explicit, the first argument is a string and it should be a number. (I don't know where `x` comes from, but it has become a string somewhere... maybe it's a `e.parameter.something` which are always strings )

simply try this code in your handler :

```
table.setWidget(Number(x),y,app.createTextBox());
```

Comment: Oooooh I thought it was something much harder. This means I really need a coffee :) Now it works well! Thank you!!!

Comment: When you're done with your coffee please consider accepting the answer :-)